# getting values from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get values from an array, For example this is array:

```
$tags_array = $_REQUEST['item'];
```

With `print_r`, I get following:

```
Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => tag1
            [1] => tag2
        )

)
```

I want to get values of array with for each loop.

```
foreach ($tags_array as $tag) {  
         echo $tag;           
       }
```

It prints nothing. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: It should at least print `Array` or something like that...

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess here and think `$tag` actually holds this type of information: `<tag>`. If you echo that in a browser it will interpret it as an actual html tag, and thereby showing nothing. Look at the html code in your browser, or do a `print_r( $tag )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two arrays, one inside another:

```
foreach ($tags_array as $tag_array) {  
         foreach ($tag_array as $tag)          
              echo $tag;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array in an array. Try this

```
foreach ($tags_array['tags'] as $tag) {  
         echo $tag;           
       }
```